# How to integrate a function of $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sin^2(u_i)\right)^{1/2}$ over a cube of edge length $\pi$?

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

How to do this integral (appearing in the context of the quantum treatment of phonons in a three-dimensional cubic lattice):

$$\prod_{j=1}^3\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}u_j\frac{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sin^2(u_i)}}{\exp\left(x\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sin^2(u_i)}\right)-1}\,,$$

where $x$ is a positive parameter. And a simpler one:

$$\prod_{j=1}^3\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}u_j\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sin^2(u_i)}\,.$$

Comment: Isn’t there a problem with your indices?

Comment: @Mindlack correct, thank you; modified.